# Using just just an amp simulator pedal for my distortion needs

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal, distortion, pre-amp

I have a cheap zoom digital effects processor which doesn't have a distortion or drive section. I am gradually switching to an analog setup. I am planning to buy a mooer gas station micro amp simulator. Right now, I don't have enough money to buy a separate distortion pedal along with the amp simulator. Can I use the amp simulator for the distortion part of the signal without using a separate distortion pedal. I am mainly into heavy metal. My signal chain will consist of the digital process for effects and modulation. This will go into the amp simulator which will go into the clean channel of my solid state amplifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am gradually switching to an analog setup. I am planning to buy a mooer gas station micro amp simulator.

The gas station is a digital pedal, so be aware that if your goal is to move to an analogue setup, the mooer is a step in the wrong direction!

> Can I use the amp simulator for the distortion part of the signal without using a separate distortion pedal.

The gas station gives you one particular distortion sound, modelled on the preamp section of one particular amp. If that is the only distortion sound you want, and as long as the output of your guitar is loud enough to drive the gas station into distortion, then you will be able to get distortion using only the gas station.

> My signal chain will consist of the digital process for effects and modulation. This will go into the amp simulator which will go into the clean channel of my solid state amplifier.

As mentioned above, the Mooer is also digital. This would mean that you are running one digital pedal into another, which is not ideal as you are going through A/D - D/A conversion twice, which increases latency. Another problem with this setup is that you might find you sometimes want your modulation and other effects *after* your distortion, rather than before - with this setup, you'd have to unplug and swap the pedals round.

If you are happy with using digital effects, it may be that you should consider getting a more flexible multi effect unit (for example, you can get a Zoom G1on for less than the cost of the Mooer), which will allow you to position effects more flexibly in your chain.

Comment: I have a zoom g1xon. The problem is the distortion section of this processor. It doesn't sound good. So I was planning on using a pedal or an amp simulator for distortion. I mostly play metal. How should I get good distortion tones with a setup that isn't too expensive?

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui what most people do is buy and sell equipment second hand until they find a setup that suits their tastes and playing style. It's hard to say what other people will like... many people find the zoom g1 easily good enough for practice purposes.

Comment: Yeah I am planning to buy second hand gear. Actually I am in a college band and we do some stage performances from time to time. The zoom doesn't sound good on stage...

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui It's often the case that gear that sounds good 'in the studio' doesn't cut through very well live - an example often mentioned is the big muff fuzz pedal, which sounds great on records but due to its frequency response can cause guitars to 'disappear' live. Nevertheless, the zoom is very configurable and there are a lot of options to try. What specific problems are you having with the sound, and what have you tried to remedy them?

Comment: My problem is with the distortion section of the processor. Whenever I use it for stage performances, it doesn't sound good. I don't know how can I describe it but it sounds shallow. Compared to other more expensive processors I have used, it's not that good. Anyway I have decided to save up for a Mooer GE200 digital processor or a Mooer-Black-Truck multi pedal...

Comment: @ZeeshanSiddiqui They look like interesting choices. The hunt for the best "tone" is all part of the fun... good luck!